# Apache POI change format Numeric

Tags: apache-poi

Using apache POI, I want to change format cell using this format :

```
style.setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("#.### "));
```

for number like this : 310.212355969299

result should be : 310.212

but in my excel, result is like this : 310.212356

Comment: Do you then remember to set that style on the cell in question?

Comment: yes I set the style after using setCellStyle(style) or by column sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(i, style);